# Two user models in a laravel application

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I'm building a SaaS web app in Laravel 5.4 where I will have my clients and the clients will have their own customers. Is it a good idea to have two user models each for clients and their customers or a single user model with roles? In case the client is also a customer of some different client, what happens then?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the main user, the end user your selling to (your client), use the model `user`

For their clients, use a model called `clients`

For organization, it would be best if your models used their own permissions. So there would be a UserRole and ClientRole table

You should be able to link the clients to the users model through has many relations. So your model structure should be similar to:

```
User
- ID
- Email
- Password

Client
- ID
- Email
- Password
- User -- relationship to /User::ID

UserRoles // Pivot Table
- ID
- Role -- relationship to /Roles::ID
- User  -- relationship to /User::ID

ClientRoles // Pivot Table
- ID
- Role -- relationship to /Roles::ID
- Client -- relationship to /Client::ID

Roles // Can also be hard coded with a ACL system
- ID
- Role Name
- ETC...
```

Personally, I like my permissions to be dynamic as much as possible, so I like to structure my roles table like this

```
Roles // Can also be hard coded with a ACL system
- ID
- Role Name
- Description
- Route URL (To pickup as an event)
```